# How can Cersei afford this in Season 7?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In season 7 Cersei attacks

> House Tyrell and gets all their gold,

in order to pay the debts to the Iron Bank and then ask their help to hire some mercenaries. But before the gold is back in King's Landing

> they're attacked by the Dothraki and a dragon, and (apparently) lose the gold.

It made me think that the support from the Iron Bank was lost too. But, in the last episode, it appears they still have the support of the Bank to hire the mercenaries.

So the question:

> Did she recover the gold after the defeat or does the Iron Bank help her without having recovered the gold?

Comment: **Spoilers**, including in the long form of the URL:  same question on [Movies and TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/78576/18476).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The gold was already in King's Landing before Dany and the Dothraki attack the **end** of the caravan train:

> Randyll Tarly: All of the gold is safely through the gates of King's Landing.
>
> Jaime Lannister: Good.
>
> Randyll Tarly: We need to get the last of these wagons over the Blackwater Rush before nightfall. If the head of the line is ambushed, the tail will never be able to reinforce in time.
>
> Jaime Lannister: We are stretched a bit thin.
>
> <sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 7 Episode 4, "The Spoils of War"</sub>

Then from the next episode we learn that the gold indeed is in the Lannister's possession. We also learn of her plan to hire mercenaries though it's only in episode 7 that we learn exactly how that plan is going to unfold.

> Cersei Lannister: It's armies that win wars. We have the Tyrell gold, we have the Iron Bank behind us. We can buy mercenaries.
>
> <sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 7 Episode 5, "Eastwatch"</sub>

Comment: Unfortunately IIRC they did make it needlessly confusing by saying "All the gold's back in King's Landing" then immediately have Jaime grab a bag of gold from a wagon to pay Bronn immediately before the fight.  Like all the gold but one wagon's in KL, I guess?

Comment: @starpilotsix Forgot about that. I guess he just saved a bag back as he wanted to give it to Bronn though why'd they put it on a wago to confuse things is beyond me.

Comment: I didn't understand that "head of the line" bit either. Isn't the head of the line the *front* of the caravan, which is presumably already inside the walls of King's Landing? How or why would the head of the line be ambushed inside the city walls?

Comment: @NuclearWang I think they're referring to the head of that section or the front that isn't already inside King's Landing. The whole quote though is a set up for how few men they have to guard the wagons.

Comment: I believe they are concerned that the train will be split across the Blackwater Rush, ie by nightfall the head of the line is on one side, while the tail is on the other.

Comment: @starpilotsix I think you might have the order wrong. I believe Jaime paid Bronn before the scene with the attack. That particular scene ends with Bronn heading off with the Tarlys to "encourage" those transferring grain.

Answer (score 14):

At the start of episode when they get attacked by the Dothraki, Old man Tarly tells Jaime that all the gold has arrived at Kings Landing. The supply wagons we see are filled with food probably.

It shows that Cersei prioritizes the gold over supplies.

Comment: Sadly I can't look for source at the moment because I am at work.

Comment: Good point in the last paragraph, what good is food for your mercenaries if you have no money to buy mercenaries with?

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam, exactly! What good is food for the people in your city when they won't grab their pitchforks and play soldier for you.

Comment: Without money you have food but no mercenaries. Without food you have mercenaries with even more reason to defeat your enemies.

Comment: +1 for "Old Man Tarly" the rascally old bigot that *really* hates foreigners :)